# Checkboxes in Listview stopped displaying after making listitems clickable & adding search function

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I am currently working on an app which has a ListView and checkboxes (disguised as favorite star icons) and is planning to used SharedPreferences after fixing some issues. My main problem started when I messed up with a CustomAdapter and another ArrayAdapter used in my main activity. My app is not crashing, but the output is very weird, kindly take a look:

Here are some important codes you might consider:

Main Activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

private ListView myListView;
ArrayAdapter<Model> myAdapter;
EditText inputSearch;
Model[] modelItems;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    // BackButton
    Button SignBackButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsignageback);
    SignBackButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });


    myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewtrial);

    modelItems = new Model[5];
    modelItems[0] = new Model("pizza", 0);
    modelItems[1] = new Model("burger", 1);
    modelItems[2] = new Model("olives", 1);
    modelItems[3] = new Model("orange", 0);
    modelItems[4] = new Model("tomato", 1);


    //////UNSOLVED PART
    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, modelItems);
    myListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    //Type entry in search textview
    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextillus);
    //////UNSOLVED PART(Conflicting codes with the CustomAdapter?)
    myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Model>(this, R.layout.search, R.id.product_name, modelItems);
    myListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    //Filter search results
    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            MyActivity.this.myAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        }
    });

    //List view for new intent?
    //Redirect listitem in new activity

    myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View item,
                                int position, long id)

        {
            String name = myListView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            for (int i = 0; i < myAdapter.getCount(); i++)
            {
                if (name.equals(modelItems[i]))
                {
                    position = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (position == 0) {
                Intent int0 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), secondactivity.class);
                startActivity(int0);
            }

            else if (position == 1) {
                Intent int1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), secondactivity.class);
                startActivity(int1);
            }
            else if (position == 2) {
                Intent int2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), secondactivity.class);
                startActivity(int2);
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Model class:

```
 public class Model{
 String name;
 int value; 

 Model(String name, int value){
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;
 }
 public String getName(){
    return this.name;
 }
 public int getValue(){
    return this.value;
 }
```

}

CursorAdaptor class:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model>{

Model[] modelItems = null;
Context context;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, Model[] resource) {
    super(context,R.layout.row,resource);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context = context;
    this.modelItems = resource;

}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
    TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    name.setText(modelItems[position].getName());
    if(modelItems[position].getValue() == 1)
        cb.setChecked(true);
    else
        cb.setChecked(false);
    return convertView;
    }



}
```

My Search XML:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/product_name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And my Row XML:

```
    <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""`enter code here`
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:button="@drawable/check"/>
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

The result is an array of incorrect string values (because it did not display the one I created) and it somewhat looks like this:

(Model is my getter setter class)

```
com.example.xxx.activity.Model@41eecd31
com.example.xxx.activity.Model@41eecd32
com.example.xxx.activity.Model@41eecd34
com.example.xxx.activity.Model@41eecd38
com.example.xxx.activity.Model@41eecd42
```

instead of

pizza
burger
olives 
orange
tomato

The checkboxes are gone. I'd greatly appreciate if someone can aid me with the disappearance of my checkboxes, and the weird display in my listitems. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have a look at the "check" drawable (@drawable/check)

also, the **[getName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName())** method would return that weird value (com.example.xxx.activity.Model@41eecd31)
show us the code for the Model class.